# ¿como puedo retroceder en git a un commit especifico, sin perder algunos datos posteriores?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Hola buenas quisiera saber ¿como puedo retroceder en git a un commit especifico, sin perder algunos datos posteriores? para restaurarlo 
¿es posible? muchas Gracias

Comment: deseas solo revisarlo o restaurarlo?

Comment: restaurarlo sin perder algunos cambios posteriores

Comment: En mi experiencia, no se podría porque estarías restaurando el archivo a una versión anterior, podrías comparar el actual con una versión anterior (commit) o consultar su contenido.

Comment: pues yo pensaba crear una rama copia, en esa rama creada retroceder hasta el commit luego agregar los comits que nesesito de la ramma original  que opinas  @Andréss

Comment: Creo que no funcionaria ya que estaría restaurada en la rama copia pero nunca esta de mas hacer la prueba.

Comment: voy a intentarlo @Andrés  haber como funciona mas tarde regreso con la respuesta haber como me fue

Comment: Significa que tienes un commit (digamos, commit0) y desde entonces hasta ahora han ocurrido N commits, en uno de los cuales rompiste o borraste algo que está en commit0 ? me parece que tendrías que hacer el trabajo manual de retroceder a commit0 en otra rama, tomar lo que quieres recuperar, volver a master y reparar a mano lo que se perdió o rompió.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola después de buscar y concejos he llegado a una solución agradable:

1. la cuestión es estando en la rama de trabajo tomar el nombre del commit desde el cual se quiere retroceder y luego utilizo git checkout **`Ej.:  git checkout 0606544`** esto me crea una rama nueva llamada ***HEAD*** que contendrá datos de regresión. ver ([git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) )
2. En este punto nos sugiere un "**git branch "nombre para rama"**" se puede realizar inmediatamente o después
3. Bueno la parte interesante esta acá donde comenzamos a copiar los commits que se quieren recuperar para eso usamos git cherry-pick **Ej.: git cherry-pick 0865866**  ver ([git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))

Comment: Si ya lo resolviste podrias aceptar tu propia respuesta ?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacer eso y todo va a depender de el caso particular, intento explicar distintos procedimientos que pueden usarse:

Por un lado, si lo que queremos es volver unos pocos archivos a como estaban antes (dejando los cambios que hicimos en el resto del repo), la opción es hacer:

```
git checkout 060654 -- app/ejemplo.js doc/*
```

Esto lo que hace es volver los archivos (pero solo esos) a una versión anterior, después de eso, se hacen los cambios necesarios y se hace un commit.

La otra opción es deshacer algunos commits que fueron mal (pero que están en master), en este caso, el comando que ayuda es:

```
git revert 819752
```

Esto hace un commit que deshace los cambios que estaban mal, pero mantiene la continuidad de la historia.

Como alternativa, si lo que se quiere es arreglar cambios que todavía no están en master, lo mejor es hacer un `rebase` *interactivo* que es más complicado pero es super potente:

```
git rebase -i master
```

Ese comando permite arreglar la historia, editando commits, reordenandolos, borrandolos, etc. En esencia lo que hace es automatizar y organizar el proceso de checkout y cherry-pick que explica [NEFEGAGO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/127440/34).